# Bootstrap navbar not collapsing not the newest version though

Tags: javascript, html, css

Maybe I'm just stupid or smth. Here is the code:
ADSHOIASDIOSAOIDSAHOIDSAOIDAS

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <title>Carti</title>
    <!-- Favicon-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" />
    <!-- Bootstrap icons-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
    <link href="/css/books.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Bibliofy</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 ms-lg-4">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/api/books">Books</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/account">Account</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">
                        <i class="bi-cart-fill me-1"></i>
                        Cart
                        <span class="badge bg-dark text-white ms-1 rounded-pill counter"><%= count %></span>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I tried getting another navbar from official bootsrap with the version but still doesnt work

Comment: What browser are you using? Is the navbar not collapsing when viewed on a smaller screen? It is collapsing nicely here, Im using Chrome.

Comment: @IceCode sorry for my autism I had other js files who are messing up the bootstrap js xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> maybe you need to add the javascript link from bootstrap to solve this
> problem, usually the navbar is using javascript both in header and
> before the closing tag of your footer add the js link in header to below footer.if it works Mark this response.